# Helping to solve XOR misunderstanding

Tags: vb.net, xor

Could somebody explain to me, why if input string from textbox is decimal 21 (`&H32 &H31`) it returns me 63 instead of 3 
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Dim BCCXOR As Integer = &H0

For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.TextLength - 1
    BCCXOR = (BCCXOR) Xor Hex(Strings.Asc(TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1).ToString()))
Next

Label1.Text = BCCXOR
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are *asking* him to use the ascii value.

The code below actually uses the number

```
Dim BCCXOR As Integer = &H0

For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.TextLength - 1
     BCCXOR = (BCCXOR) Xor Hex(Cint(TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 1).ToString()))
Next

Label1.Text = BCCXOR
```